# Use arabic string in Spring MVC application properties file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, internationalization, arabic

I have a language dropdown in my web application which has English and Arabic. I have these values in my `application.properties` file. Below is how I have the configuration for the language dropdown.

```
languages=[ {"name": "English", "code": "EN"}, {"name": "العربية", "code": "AR"}]
```

> Now when I access this configuration and populate the dropdown, String
>   in Arabic is showing weird characters. I am also using Thymeleaf as my
>   frontend rendering framework. How to get the Arabic string using this
>   configuration or is there any other better alternative.

Thanks

Comment: Use unicodes for such characters or set utf-8 as meta data  in html pages.

Answer (score 1):

What I actually did is, in my **i18n** folder, I am using a property file to hold arabic strings. There I used a config as `AR=العربية`. Then in my html file, to display the arabic string, i did `<span th:text="#{__${language.code}__}">العربية</span>`

So, what is happening now is, I am reading the arabic string from the **i18n** arabic messages property file to display arabic string.